# Why do ReactDOMServer and ReactDOM give the "root.hydrate is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npx

When creating an app using `create-react-app` I get the following error when trying to use `hydrate` instead of the default `.render`. Here is the `src/index.js` file's contents.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOMServer.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.hydrate(
 <React.StrictMode>
   <App />
 </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Running the above code `npm start` produces the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: root.hydrate is not a function
```

The error is not present if I change the `.hydrate` back to `.render` and I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: What version of `React` are you using?

Comment: I am using React version 18.1.0

Answer (score 3):

> `hydrate` has been replaced with `hydrateRoot` in React 18.

```
hydrateRoot(container, element[, options])
```

You can check for more info about `hydrateRoot` here : [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-client.html#hydrateroot)

```js
// Before React 18
import { hydrate } from 'react-dom';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
hydrate(<App tab="home" />, container);

// After React 18+
import { hydrateRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = hydrateRoot(container, <App tab="home" />);
// Unlike with createRoot, you don't need a separate root.render() call here.
```

Comment: Thanks so much @PR7, I responded in the form of an "answer" because it did not seem possible to show my code blocks in one of these comment boxes (which have limited characters also).
Your solution worked perfectly and the link to the documentation was very handy and much appreciated.
Kind regards
Tim (tpmccallum)

Comment: @tpmccallum Happy to help. Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @PR7 that worked perfectly.

Please note, as my original file syntax was slightly different (from your example), I have written my "before" and "after" below; in case it can help anyone else.

```
// Before
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.hydrate(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <App />
 </React.StrictMode>
);

// After

import { hydrateRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = hydrateRoot(container, <App />);
```